# Endpoint URL to connect the Dialogflow CX agent to WhatsApp using Twilio

Tags: twilio, google-cloud-endpoints, dialogflow-cx

I created an agent in Dialogflow CX and I would like to integrate my bot with WhatsApp using Twilio. For this, I have enabled the Dialogflow API, Service Account, Twilio Account etc., but for the text which the Twilio number receives, that message has to be sent to the bot for further interactions and I understood that we need an endpoint URL. However, I am unable to understand how to get this URL. Is it something I can do with code (like writing a python file and running to get the URL) or do I need to use Cloud Functions or Cloud Run.

I would like to know where I can find the endpoint URL for my Dialogflow CX agent and how to get that URL.